# JQuery jqplot legend not showing good

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a chart using jQplot. It works good but I want to have a legend like http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php . But my legend is not working like on jqplot website. The picture of the output shown below. Anybody notice what i miss? Here i attach the code

```
$('#tes').live('pageshow', function() {
        var data = [
['A', 12],['B', 9], ['C', 14],
['D', 16],['E', 7]];
var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data],
{
  seriesDefaults: {
    // Make this a pie chart.
    renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
      // Put data labels on the pie slices.
      // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
      showDataLabels: true,
      dataLabels: 'value'
    }
  },
  legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
}
);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solve the problem. the problem is because i haven't add jquery.jqplot.css file

Answer (score 0):

You may have not added jquery.jqplot.css.
Ensure that you have Added the following js and css:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.jqplot.css" type="text/css" />
```